# Objective regex evaluateWithObject is not working

Tags: iphone, regex

When I tried matching the string with the regex `'^(34|37)'` it does not work even after giving the correct one.  Can anyone please point out or guide me to what I am doing wrong?
This is my code:

```
NSPredicate *myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"^(34|37)"];
if([myTest evaluateWithObject: @"378282246310005"]){
   NSLog(@"match");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex will not match the given string.  That is `^(34|37)` does not match `378282246310005`.  It matches the first two characters, but after that it fails because the string contains more characters, while your regex terminates.

You need to alter your regex to match the rest of the characters, even if you don't want to capture them.  Try changing your regext to `^(34|37).*`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use `hasPrefix`:

```
if([@"378282246310005" hasPrefix:@"34"] || [@"378282246310005" hasPrefix:@"37"])
{
   NSLog(@"found it");
}
```

**EDIT:**

Using `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate *myTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", @"^3(4|7)\\d+$"];

    if([myTest evaluateWithObject: @"378282246310005"])
    {
        NSLog(@"match");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"notmatch");
    }
```

Using `NSRegularExpression`:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *testStr = @"348282246310005";

NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"^3(4|7)" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

NSInteger matches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:testStr options:NSMatchingReportCompletion range:NSMakeRange(0, [testStr length])];

if(matches > 0 )//[myTest evaluateWithObject: @"378282246310005"])
{
    NSLog(@"match");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"notmatch");
}
```

BTW: `(34|37)` does not look `34` or `37` instead it seems `347` or `337` to me, since engine will pick `4|3` either `4` or `3`.

Answer (score 0):

Make seprate method for matching regex as bool type. Then it will work.

like this

```
- (IBAction)tapValidatePhone:(id)sender
{
 if(![self validateMobileNo:self.txtPhoneNo.text] )
{
    NSLog(@"Mobile No. is not valid");
}
}

-(BOOL) validateMobileNo:(NSString *) paramMobleNo
 {
 NSString *phoneNoRegex = @"^(34|37)";
 NSPredicate *phoneNoTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@",phoneNoRegex];
return [phoneNoTest evaluateWithObject:@"3435"];

}
```

it is not going in else condition.